# Sending JSONP from PHP site to multiple sites

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I am a newb with JSONP so I am hoping someone will help me from the ground up.

Basically my situation is:

I have a server with a CMS. I want information from the CMS to appear on several other sites.

So I am thinking (but am unsure) that I put the information I want to transmit in a PHP variable. I then use

```
echo json_encode($json);
```

then on the sites I wish to display the information on I use JQuery to:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.mycmssite.com/phppage.php?json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: json,
  success: callback
});

var myvar = success;
document.write(myvar);
```

Now this is my preliminary understanding and I know its full of holes. But if someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome!

Thanks heaps!

Comment: It seems OK. Try it. But don't forget to set [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) if you want various sites to access your json data.

Comment: `var myvar = success; document.write(myvar);` is stange. Your callback function must set (and use) the data.

Comment: thanks dystroy - this is what I am having trouble understanding: Can you write me an example of how you would do this line? And by CORS header do you mean something like: header("content-type: application/json");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Ajax requests specifies `dataType: 'jsonp'` instead. This will allow the call to get around the same-origin policy and add a jQuery generated callback function name.

Make sure your server script can detect the fact that a callback function name was passed and that it wraps the response within that function.

For example, when your service is called with a callback:

```
http://www.mycmssite.com/phppage.php?json=1&callback= jQuery17109598642324563116
```

your response will be something like:

```
jQuery17109598642324563116({json response here})
```

Also, the success property should be set to an existing function that will execute some logic on the JSON data it receives.

- Read the [documentation for $.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for details on the other properties, like data, to be sure you understand what's expected here.

Comment: Now that we have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control) we don't need to use JSONP anymore.

Comment: Right, as long as your application does not need to support older browsers, IE 6 and 7. I am simply answering the question asked.

Comment: Yes. I just don't think we should support IE7 anymore but you're technically totally right.

Comment: Thanks guys p think Im getting there. Just another question: Must you add a PHP method to call the data? ie: Does the $.ajax "invoke" the php function on the first server?

Comment: $.ajax doesn't invoke a php function but your php page, just like when you call it directly by putting the URL in the URL bar of your browser.

Comment: Yes. Ajax/JavaScript does not care what the server language is as long as the response is valid, in this case valid JSON.

Comment: OK I think Im almost there: In the console i get the work GET followed by the url and a whole heap of digits: GET http://localhost/mbff_cms/?jsoncallback=jQuery1...etc

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.mycmssite.com/phppage.php?json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {Iwant:'theData', thisIs:'somejson'},
    success: function(msg) {
        console.log('server answered:', msg);
        // do something with received message
    }
});
```

The CORS headers are more like

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
header("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET")
header("content-type", "application/x-javascript")
```

Those headers make the requirement for JSONP obsolete.

Comment: OK I am really close, heres what Im getting in the console:
GET http://localhost/mbff_cms/?jsoncallback=jQuery1720037476439494639635_1338898608215&jsoncallback=jsoncallback&_=1338898608228  jquery-1.7.2.js:8123